# How to create a search in real time with MEAN Stack?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, angular, express

Is there an simple example of creating real time DB search with MEAN stack, I am only having knowledge in MEN and I would love to learn Angular 2.

Right now I am working on simple Enterprise project where I need to go trough DB with live search and display matchings for name || description || anything else.

Thank you for any advice and example.

Comment: From your explanation, it looks like you might need a Elasticsearch. https://www.elastic.co/webinars/getting-started-elasticsearch?elektra=home&storm=banner

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'll take a look at Elasticsearch

Comment: go for elasticsearch all the way I've written a blog post about using elasticsearch with MEAN stack, https://madhacker.me/elasticsearch-and-the-mean-stack/

Comment: Awesome blog post, this will help me a lot!